# Динамический запрос @Query с двумя таблицами, Spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

мне нужно написать запрос, который будет выводить данные из MYSQL в соответствии с данными, которые пользователь ввел при регистрации. У меня есть две таблицы и две @Entity к ним.
**Таблица из которой нужно выбирать данные - "table"**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
public class Table {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private int subject;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private int groupofstudent;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private int courseofstudent;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String monday;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String tuesday;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String wednesday;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String thursday;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String friday;

    public int getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(int subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public int getGroupofstudent() {
        return groupofstudent;
    }

    public void setGroupofstudent(int groupofstudent) {
        this.groupofstudent = groupofstudent;
    }

    public int getCourseofstudent() {
        return courseofstudent;
    }

    public void setCourseofstudent(int courseofstudent) {
        this.courseofstudent = courseofstudent;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMonday() {
        return monday;
    }

    public void setMonday(String monday) {
        this.monday = monday;
    }

    public String getTuesday() {
        return tuesday;
    }

    public void setTuesday(String tuesday) {
        this.tuesday = tuesday;
    }

    public String getWednesday() {
        return wednesday;
    }

    public void setWednesday(String wednesday) {
        this.wednesday = wednesday;
    }

    public String getThursday() {
        return thursday;
    }

    public void setThursday(String thursday) {
        this.thursday = thursday;
    }

    public String getFriday() {
        return friday;
    }

    public void setFriday(String friday) {
        this.friday = friday;
    }
}
```

**Таблица с данными пользователя - "User"**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(unique = true, length = 45, nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @Column(length = 45, nullable = false)
    private String passwordof;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int course;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int groupofstudent;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return passwordof;
    }

    public void setPassword(String passwordof) {
        this.passwordof = passwordof;
    }

    public int getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(int course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public int getGroupofstudent() {
        return groupofstudent;
    }

    public void setGroupofstudent(int groupofstudent) {
        this.groupofstudent = groupofstudent;
    }
}
```

**Репозиторий для таблицы "table"**

```
@Repository
public interface TableRepository extends JpaRepository<Table, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT t FROM Table t WHERE t.courseofstudent= 1 and t.groupofstudent= 1")
    List<table> findByGroupofstudentAndCourseofstudent();
}
```

Этот запрос работает.

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM table t WHERE t.courseofstudent= 1 and t.groupofstudent= 1")
```

Но мне нужно брать данные каждого пользователя и динамически изменять две единицы на поля groupofstudent и courseofstudent из таблицы **"User"**. Также другие части кода:
**Контроллер**

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private TableService tableService;

    public void setCustomUserDetailsService(CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService){
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
    }

    public void setTableService(F_fitService tableService){
        this.tableService = tableService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/schedule")
    public String schedulePage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("groupandcourse", customUserDetailsService.listAllUsers());
        model.addAttribute("subjects", tableService.getSubjectByGroupAndCourse());
        return "SchedulePage";
    }
}
```

**Сервис**

```
@Service
public class TableService {

    @Autowired
    private TableRepository tableRepository;

    public List<table> getSubjectByGroupAndCourse(){
        return tableRepository.findByGroupofstudentAndCourseofstudent();
    }
}
```

Как мне осуществить динамический запрос используя данные из двух таблиц?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вкратце:

1. Передаешь поля *groupofstudent* и *courseofstudent* в параметры контроллера, например, в PathVariable
2. Прокидываешь их выше в свой сервис, далее в репо
3. И твой метод будет выглядеть так:

> ```
> @Query("SELECT t FROM Table t WHERE t.courseofstudent= :courseofstudent and t.groupofstudent= :groupofstudent")
> List<table> findByGroupofstudentAndCourseofstudent(@Param("courseofstudent") int courseofstudent, @Param("groupofstudent") int groupofstudent);
> ```